# Laravel constructor and method injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am having an issue setting up an injection on both the constructor and the method in a controller.

What I need to achieve is to be able to set up a global controller variable without injecting the same on the controller method.

From below route;

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test/{five}'], function(){
    Route::get('/index/{admin}', 'TestController@index');
});
```

I want the five to be received by the constructor while the admin to be available to the method.
Below is my controller;

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $five;

    public function __construct(PrimaryFive $five, Request $request)
    {
        $this->five = $five;
    }

    public function index(Admin $admin, Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->segments(), $admin);
        return 'We are here: ';
    }
...
```

When I run the above, which I'm looking into using, I get an error on the index method:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\TestController::index() must be an instance of App\Models\Admin, string given"

Below works, but I don't need the PrimaryFive injection at the method.

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $five;

    public function __construct(PrimaryFive $five, Request $request)
    {
        $this->five = $five;
    }

    public function index(PrimaryFive $five, Admin $admin, Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->segments(), $five, $admin);
        return 'We are here: ';
    }
...
```

Is there a way I can set the constructor injection with a model (which works) and set the method injection as well without having to inject the model set in the constructor?

Comment: Is this just for this one controller or will you be wanting to add it to more/all of your controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is to use [controller middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#controller-middleware):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function (Request $request, $next) {

        $this->five = PrimaryFive::findOrFail($request->route('five'));

        $request->route()->forgetParameter('five');

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

The above is assuming that `PrimaryFive` is an Eloquent model.

This will mean that `$this->five` is set for the controller, however, since we're using `forgetParameter()` it will no longer be passed to your controller methods.

---

If you've specific used [Route::model() or Route::bind()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding) to resolve your `five` segment then you can retrieve the instance straight from `$request->route('five')` i.e.:

```
$this->five = $request->route('five');
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is because of you cannot pass a model through the route. it should be somethiing like `/index/abc` or `/index/123`.

you can use your index function as below

```
public function index($admin,Request $request){}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will surely help you.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'test/{five}'], function () {
    Route::get('/index/{admin}', function ($five, $admin) {
        $app = app();
        $ctr = $app->make('\App\Http\Controllers\TestController');
        return $ctr->callAction("index", [$admin]);
    });
});
```

**Another way to call controller from the route. You can control what do you want to pass from route to controller**